# My project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version Flutter uses for Gradle

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, version-control

First I want to say that I wanted to run a flutter program on my cell phone that was connected by USB to my PC, but the following appeared in the console:

Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using
for Gradle.

To fix this issue, consult the migration guide at docs.flutter.dev/go/android-java-gradle-error.

What you're looking for means that the versions of java or gradle you use are incompatible.

----------------------------SOLUTION----------------------------

The Gradle version change ended up working for me, since I have version 20 of Java and the one compatible with it is Gradle 8.1 to 8.3 based on what was said on the following compatibility page [-pagina-](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)

There is also a page with a description and indications in each version of Gradle's compatibility with Java[-pagina-](https://gradle.org/releases/)

Taking that into account, you should know what version of Java you have to compare them on the previous pages and verify which version of Gradle will work for you. In my case, I have Java version 20 and I had Gradle 7.5, which did not work for me and would not let me. run the program so I changed to gradle version 8.2 and it worked normally.

To change the version of the Flutter program, you must enter the following sections:

[imagen de explorador de visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNhaH.png)
In that section of the explorer open the folder called android

[imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyqYQ.png)Inside the android folder you must open gradle and finally the gradle-wrapper.properties file where the link to the gradle version is located:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

The last line is the link that must be changed, from 7.5 I changed it to 8.2 (gradle version compatible with my version of java), leaving it like this:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-all.zip

I hope it can be useful to someone

Comment: answers go in answer posts